# How I can determine when a window handle is valid?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am writing a DLL which make some operations on a particular window, but sometimes the handle passed is not valid. Does there exist any function to validate that the handle passed is valid (belongs to a window)?

Comment: Under what conditions is the window handle not valid? Window handles are recycled so a window handle that was valid, and then invalid, could be valid again, but pointing to a completely different window.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try using the [`IsWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which is declared in the Windows unit.

```
function IsWindow(hWnd: HWND): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Comment: +1. This is the right answer. [`IsWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633528(v=vs.85).aspx) is a function of the Windows API.